# Can I locally fix an imported library's incorrect types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm using [passport-saml](https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml) to do SAML authentication. Recently they made a change where a `MultiSamlStrategy`'s constructor should take a `privateKey` property instead of a `privateCert` property, with the latter leading to a warning at runtime. To avoid the warning, I'm currently using `@ts-expect-error` to ignore the typing issue:

```
// @ts-expect-error https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml/pull/497
privateKey: privateKey,
```

I don't really like this style of ignoring errors in my source code that I know are present. Is there a way I can define the correct types locally and tell TypeScript to use those instead? I know about the existence of [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), but I haven't been able to construct a formulation that works. Ideally, I'd just add the `privateKey` property to the `SamlConfig` interface -- I don't need to remove any properties.

Comment: Did you try adding to the namespace in a type declaration file?

Comment: Yes. I've tried namespaces of "MultiSamlStrategy" (for the class), "passport-saml", "passport-saml/lib/passport-saml/types" and also global. Nothing I've picked has had an effect. The declaration file exported by this project only exports `MultiSamlStrategy`, rather than a namespace containing everything.

Comment: not sure what the exact problem is, but can you try: import * as ps  from 'passport-saml'; class MultiSamlStrategy extends ps.MultiSamlStrategy { constructor(privateKey: privateKey) {super(...);  ...} }, something like that?